# Python Fibonacci sequence error

Tags: python

this was one of the problems I was assigned in MyProgrammingLab. I've attempted to answer this problem over 45 times, but can't get it right. 
Any help will be appreciated

Question:
In the following sequence, each number (except the first two) is the sum of the previous two numbers: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, .... This sequence is known as the Fibonacci sequence.

We speak of the i'th element of the sequence (starting at 0)-- thus the 0th element is 0, the 1st element is 1, the 2nd element is 1, the 3rd element is 2 and so on. Given the positive integer n, associate the nth value of the fibonacci sequence with the variable  result. For example, if n is associated with the value 8 then result would be associated with 21.

My work:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        result == n
    elif n >= 1:
        result = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    else:
        return result
```

Comment: Seriously? You have an `if` and `elif` with the same condition! Also you only return in neither case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in all of your cases, you *assign* the result but don't return it.

So, for example, when `fib(1)` is called, Python returns `None` because you never told it to return `result` in that case. The same thing happens for, say, `fib(45)`.

To correct this, just return `result` always. (This is a good idea no matter what type of program you are writing - functions should always have an explicit return value).

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        result = n
    elif n > 1:
        result = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    return result # always return result!
```

### Things to Know

- You should be aware that this implementation of the Fibonacci sequence is the least efficient one out there. If you can ditch the recursive calls altogether and just use a `while` loop to calculate `fib(n)` - or, if you want recursion, store previously computed values of `fib(n)` instead of forcing it to compute all the way to `fib(n)` - you will have a much more efficient implementation.
- Your code contained numerous issues, such as

  - Assigning without returning, which we've already discussed.
  - Using `==` instead of `=`. The first checks if the left and right  hand side are *equal*, and returns `True` or `False`. The second actually assigns the value of the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side. Don't confuse checking for equality with assignment.
  - Using the same base case twice but telling Python to do something different in both cases. This is such a bad idea that I feel jonrsharpe in the comments is justified in saying "Seriously?". The reason for this is because doing this makes no sense and makes it hard to predict behaviour. The whole point of an `if-else` statement is to do *different* things in different cases.
  - *Edit based on examples provided by OP*. Indentation should only be *four* spaces, not *eight*. This is more of a stylistic issue than anything else, but it is the standard.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I see my mistake. But, MyProgrammingLab is asking for an else statement, which I used and ended up with this code
http://hastebin.com/idebizogus.py
It is still not accepting the code. Any reason why?

Comment: @Jason Just `return result` in your `if`, `elif` and `else` statements, obviously. And you're making a serious, serious, _serious_ mistake again: why would you check for `n<=1` and `n>=1` at the same time? What case do you expect is going to get run when `n` equals 1?

Comment: @Jason Other issue: Do you really _need_ an `elif` condition. Think: if you have `n <= 1`, why not just do `if n <= 1: return n; else: return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`? Do you understand why this works? It's because `else` will take care of all cases that the foregoing `if` doesn't. `elif` is to be used when you have more than just two cases to support,

Comment: The result of this http://hastebin.com/vapevecisa.py is this http://prntscr.com/awcl8f.

Comment: @Jason IF you try this out on your own machine, I suspect you'll find it works perfectly. MyProgrammingLab is doubtless trying to get you to do things its way. I suspect it wants something like `if n == 1: return 1; if n == 0: return 0; else: return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`.

Comment: I see what you mean. It does run on my own machine. But, I still can't figure it out on MPL. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

You can essentially reduce it to this. You could even leave out the else and say:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

but you said you need to have an else-case for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one for my assignment. I know it's a little indirect, but it works and that's what's important :)

```
n = int(input("Insert a number: "))
i = 0
fib_list = [1, 1, 0]
for i in range (0,2):
    if n == 0:
        result = fib_list[2]
    elif n <= 2:
        result = fib_list[0]
for i in range (2,n):
        result = fib_list[0] + fib_list[1]
        fib_list.insert(0, result)
        i += 1
        result = fib_list[0]
```

By the way, you don't need to define an input to use in the myprogramminglab question.

I added the input version here because I used it in my tests.